# Freefall and shock detection algorithm in kernel

Tags: c, accelerometer, sensors

I am implementing a bma220 accelerometer device to detect free fall and shock.I have two confusions regarding implementing these features,

1) For freefall interrupt, the sensor should be in 2g mode

2) For shock interrupt, the sensor should be in 8g mode

this is the small code I am using to write on bma220 registers

```
    set_bma_data(REG_GMODE, 0x00);//REG GMODE 0x22
    set_bma_data(REG_FILTER, 0x00);
    set_bma_data(EN_LOW, 0x08);//for low g interrupt or free fall detection
    set_bma_data(LOW_HY, 0XFF);
    set_bma_data(LOW_TH, 0xF0);
```

If yes how can the sensor be configured in both modes as we can configure our sensor in only one g mode?

Comment: Related but not a straight duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/127479/data-from-bma220-accelerometer